# How do vCPUs utilize the logical processors (hardware threads) of a physical host?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, logical-processor

For example, if I have a single-core physical CPU with two hardware threads (i.e. logical processors), and a single-core vCPU VM running on the particular host (the vCPU corresponds to a logical processor of the physical CPU), will the vCPU utilize the same logical processor of the physical host during the duration (continuous time) it is busy? Or is it possible that it may be assigned different logical processors during its busy time?

Answer (score 0):

[Processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) depends on the hardware platform and OS in use.